# Exporting a variable set in a function to another component React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some variables that are set within a function in one component of my react application that I need to reuse in other components.

I set the variables in component 1 like so (this is a much simplified version but captures the structure)

```
    export default function Example() {
                const [market, setMarket] = useState('');
        return ( 
<button onClick={setMarket('1')}>Click 1</button>
    <button onClick={setMarket('2')}>Click 2</button>
    <button onClick={setMarket('3')}>Click 3</button> )}
```

How can I export the 'market' variable specifically, so that I can import it into another component (in a separate jsx file) and render as necessary. I know that I can just import the whole component, or set a variable outside of this function in component 1 and export it but I do not know how I would then conditionally set it based on which button is clicked.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hey @Milo there are different ways to use state value in another component.

1. First is props-
   Create a component that passes values like-

   const passValue = () => {
   const [ value, setValue ] = useState("")
   return (

   )
    }

While in the second component we get the value like-

```
const SecondComponent = ({value})=>{
return(
<div>
{value}
</div>
)
}
```

2. While Second method is to pass value using state and get it by useLocation in another component-

First Component like-

```
const FirstComponent = () =>{
return(
<div>
<Link to="/secondpage" state={{value:yourValue/state}}>Click Here</Link>
</div>
)
}
```

Second Component Like-

```
const Second Component = () => {
const {state} = useLocation()
return(
<div>{state}</div>
)
}
```

Hope these solution helps to solve your problem. If you still facing issue lemme know, i will help you.
Thanks